# BEGIN: command not found in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program but when I am trying to run it, it's throwing the error

```
*****BEGIN: command not found
+ our =/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/lib
/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/bin/FileTransfer.pl: line 4: our: command not found
+ push @INC,
/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/bin/FileTransfer.pl: line 5: push: command not found
/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/bin/FileTransfer.pl: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/bin/FileTransfer.pl: line 6: `}'*****
```

I think the error is due to the fact that its trying to run the script via the shell instead of via perl. I have checked all the basic things, like there is no extra line before the she bang in my script. But still i am not able to figure out what the exact prob is.

Here is the start of our code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
BEGIN {
  our $lib_path="/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/lib";
  push @INC, $lib_path;
}
```

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 environment.

Comment: Call it "Perl", not "PERL". It will hate you otherwise. Then show us some code, especially the shebang line. And show us your command line.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
 
BEGIN {
our $lib_path="/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/lib";
push @INC, $lib_path;
}

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct.  It is not being interpreted as Perl but as a shell script.  Try invoking it by saying `/path/to/perl filename`.

Comment: `use lib $lib_path`. please dont use your way of adding libs.

Comment: Interesting, indeed. The code is syntactically correct. How do you invoke it exactly? How did you create the file? Is there everything OK with /usr/bin/perl binary? Try the following command (I enclosed code within double colons) :: echo 'BEGIN { print "xxx\n"; }' | perl  :: if this works, i.e. prints xxx as expected, then there's something wrong with perl binary or with the file itself. If it does not, maybe system was compromised and some binaries replaced, or damaged because of filesystem/disk problem?

Comment: thanks a lot ppl...@PiotrWadas - the prob is that this one is part of a job that is scheduled in control m scheduler tool and i am not sure how they run the scripts from there..syntactically the script looks fine and the manual run is doing fine too..prob is arising when we run the same script via control m tool.

Comment: My bet would be the script is called from inside bash script, with bash's "source" command, or something like that.

Comment: ok....so u r saying to call this perl script from a bash script..rght????

Comment: No. And your free to menatally add any number of exclamation marks to that "No".

Comment: One reason a shebang line will be ignored in Un*x is if there is an unexpected carriage return character (`\r`) on it. Check your line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it is interpreted as bash script. If shebang line is exactly as you pasted it, then it must be something wrong with perl binary. Don't you try to run it invalid way e.g. with "bash test.pl", or "source test.pl" from shell? Anyway the code is syntactically correct.

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl 

BEGIN {
  our $lib_path="/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/lib";
  push @INC, $lib_path;
  print $lib_path . "\n";
}
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ bash test.pl 
test.pl: line 3: BEGIN: command not found
test.pl: line 4: our: command not found
test.pl: line 5: push: command not found
test.pl: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
test.pl: line 6: `}'
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ ./test.pl 
/prod/home01/appl/psoft/epmapp/batch/lib
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Comment: No. I am saying this perl script is called invalid way in your environment, as shown by "emulating" invalid call.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't stop the perl script being executed as a shell script, then adding the magic lines

```
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0; # not running under some shell
```

below the shebang might help.